# Changing grails "no conversion strategy" error that is not in message.properties

Tags: grails

Is there a way to change Grails conversion mismatch error to custom message?

I am getting:

> Failed to convert property value of type `java.lang.String` to required
>   type `java.util.Map` for property `items`;nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map] for property
>   items: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

This error type is not in `messages.properties`. I am getting this if a user tries to inject request parameter which is not a map into my Command Object, they shouldn't be doing this, but that besides the point:

```
class CartCommand implements Serializable {
  Map<Integer, Integer> items = 
                MapUtils.lazyMap([:], FactoryUtils.constantFactory(''))
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following key in your `message.properties`:

```
cartCommand.items.typeMismatch.map
```